# How to show the details of a particular row in a modal when row is clicked in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS. I'm converting some pages to AngularJS. I just displayed rows of information. However I'm having trouble converting the button onclick part to AngularJS. Can someone please help me. Below is the code that I'm working with.

```
<div ng-repeat="i in data">
 <p>{{i.name}}</p>
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".show-ticket-details-modal" onclick="show_details(10)">
          <i class="fa fa-info"></i>
        </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the model to show_details method

```
show_details(i)
```

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ng-click` (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick). This runs a function in your angular controller when you click an element. All you've got to do is add the `ng-click` directive to your element, and then build a function with the same name in your angular controller to handle the data.

IE, replace `onclick="show_details(10)"` with: `ng-click="show_details(10)"`.

Then, in your controller, build a function with the same name that will handle the data `show_details(10)`, like:

```
$scope.show_details = function(index) { 
    console.log(index); // will log 10 in the example above
    // do stuff with your index here, 
    // pass data to your angular factory, etc.
};
```

Note: For `<form>` elements, you can use the `ng-submit` directive instead (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit). Just use `ng-submit="someFunction()"` instead of `ng-click`.

#### Another Idea:

Instead of passing in the number `10`, you could also use `track by $index` (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#), for example, in your `ng-repeat`, you could:

```
ng-repeat="i in data track by $index"
```

Now, you can actually just pass `$index` into your `ng-click` function, instead of the number `10`:

```
ng-click="show_details($index)" // $index will be 10, if the index of `i` was 10 in `data`
```

Hope this helps somewhat, let me know if you have any questions! The links included show more examples of their usage!

Comment: thanks a lot for the detailed example. This is my ng-repeat="i in data | searchFor:searchString" how do I insert track by $index here?

Comment: @Krish You just add `track by index` as the very last parameter (without a pipe `|` character), so it would be: `ng-repeat="i in data | searchFor: searchString track by $index"`